# Another topology question

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, formal-proofs

This is a two part question. The first part, part (i), I present with the solution I reached. The second part, part (ii) is where I need help.

(i) Let $B$ be a basis for a topology $T$ on a non-empty set $X$. If $B_1$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $T\supseteq B_1\supseteq B$, prove that $B_1$ is also a basis for $T$.

Let $U$ denote any open set in the topology. Since $B$ is a basis for the topology, we know that any open set $U=\bigcup_{i\in j} B_j, B_j \in B$ for all j,

But since $B_1 \supseteq B$, we know that $B_j \in B_1$ for all j, and so thus:
$U=\bigcup_{i\in j} B_j, B_j \in B_1$ for all j. Any open set in the topology is therefore a union of members of $B_1$ showing that $B_1$ is indeed a basis for the topology.

So far, I'm ok. But then this I have trouble with:

(ii) Deduce from (i) that there exists an uncountable number of distinct bases for the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Please **dumb down** the explanation as much as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Two questions first. $(1)$ Do you know that $\Bbb R$ has a countable base? $(2)$ Do you know that the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ has uncountably many open sets?

Comment: Well, there is a somewhat canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}$ which is "small" in that it is countable, namely the set of open intervals $(q-r,q+r)$, $q,r\in\mathbb{Q}, r>0$. How might you go from there?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well I know that that the $\Bbb{R}$ have a countable basis which is the set of all pairs of rational numbers $\Bbb{Q}$ $\times$ $\Bbb{Q}$. Also I would expect that the usual basis of open discs is uncountable but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @user224530: You could prove it by showing that if $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and $x\ne y$, then $(x-1,x+1)\ne(y-1,y+1)$. However, I've suggested something even simpler in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the base of open intervals with rational endpoints. Note that for each $x\in\Bbb R$ the set $U_x=\Bbb R\setminus\{x\}$ is open and not in $\mathscr{B}$. Now use your first result to get uncountably many different bases for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: So what your saying is that I should take $U_x$ and include it in $\Re$ giving me a basis for each $x \in \Bbb R$ ? Just two questions: $(1)$ Can't each $U_x$ be generated by $\Re$ through infinite unions approaching $x$ from each side? And, $(2)$ Did you choose this construction because each $U_x$ is open in the Euclidean topology but not included in $\Re$? Please tell me more about why you chose this construction. Thanks.